# How to get Base class reference in java from Child class element in XML

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am having a XML which look like

```
<Record>
  <Student>
    <name>sumit</name>
    <rollno>123</rollno>
  <Student>
<Record>
```

and model classes looks like

```
class Record{
    @JsonProperty("person")
    private Person person;
    public String getPerson(){
      return person;
    }
    public void setPerson(String person){
      this.person=person;
    }
}

abstract class Person{
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
      return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
      this.name=name;
    }
}

@JsonTypeName("Student")
class Student extends Person{
    @JsonProperty("rollno")
    private String rollno;
    public String getrollno(){
      return rollno;
    }
    public void setName(String rollno){
      this.rollno=rollno;
    }
}
```

Now in my application i am creating object from XML as below

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/sumit/abc.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Record.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Record data = (Record) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

But i am getting `null` in data.getPerson();

Can Anyone help me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work the way you want it to. XML elements are identified by tag names, and tag names need to correspond to field names in a Java class. Once `<Record>` has been established as a value of class `Record`, `<Student>` has no counterpart in a field of that class, and JAXB cannot unmarshal this content.

You should be able to unmarshal 8after changing `<Student>` to `<student>`) with this modified class:

```
class Record{
    private Student student;
    public Student getStudent(){
         return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student value){
        student = value;
    }
}
```

(Note that there is another problem due to the type mismatch String vs. Person for the person field in class Record.)